# Can you get your current location in Geotools?

Tags: java, android, gps, geotools

I'm working on location sensitive application in Java, and [GeoTools](https://www.geotools.org/) seems to be the open source library everyone loves working with.

However, **I'm wondering if there's a way to get the user's current location with GeoTools**? Is that something you can even do?

I've been Googling examples and touring through the documentation, but it looks like it's just expecting the user to manually report their location and perform analyses from there:

[image: documentation on location.csv]

...is this possible? IF not, is there a better tool in Java or even Android that will work?

Comment: You do not need a tool to determine location of an Android device. It is just using some functions.

Comment: GeoTools doesn't run on Android and has no way to access a GPS peripheral directly.